# The same item is being deleted twice after executing Network Call in a loop

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I am facing a strange problem. I am trying to delete the selected items from the `mysql database`. Though everything for the query is correct and i tested the query and it works but it does not delete items from database.

The code:

```
private class DeleteData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<CartList>> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(CartActivity.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.get_stocks));
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected List<CartList> doInBackground(String... params) {
    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
    cartItems = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        url = new URL(params[0]);
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
        httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        deleteDataInDB();
        outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
        bufferedWriter.write(StringGenerator.queryResults(nameValuePairs));
        bufferedWriter.flush();
        bufferedWriter.close();
        outputStream.close();
        httpURLConnection.connect();
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
        jsonResult = StringGenerator.inputStreamToString(inputStream, CartActivity.this);
        Log.e("Response: ", jsonResult.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cartItems;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<CartList> cartLists) {
    super.onPostExecute(cartLists);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
}
```

The setup Method:

```
private void deleteDataInDB(){

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(AppConstant.PRODUCT_NAME_VALUE_PAIR, nameAdapter));
        Log.e("Name Adapter Value: ", nameAdapter);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(AppConstant.COMPANY_INTENT_ID, magazi_id));
        Log.e("Magazi id: ", magazi_id);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(AppConstant.PRODUCT_WAITER_ID_VALUE_PAIR, servitoros_id));
        Log.e("Servitoros id: ", servitoros_id);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(AppConstant.PRODUCT_TABLE_ID_VALUE_PAIR, table));
        Log.e("Table: ", table);
    }
```

Where i execute the task:

```
@Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.deleteCartItemModification:{
                    for (int position = 0; position<names.size(); position++){
                        nameAdapter = names.get(position);
                        deleteDataWebService();
                        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    }
                    setupTotalValue();
                    Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Items Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CartActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.delete));
                    builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.delete_msg));
                    builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            deleteDataWebService();
                            Toast.makeText(CartActivity.this, "Items Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.create();
                    builder.show();
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
```

The response:

```
    12-17 05:37:24.043 2099-2099/com.order.app.order E/Names Added:: [BLT Sandwich, Club Sandwich]
12-17 05:37:24.045 2099-2099/com.order.app.order I/AppCompatDelegate: The Activity's LayoutInflater already has a Factory installed so we can not install AppCompat's
12-17 05:37:24.086 2099-2118/com.order.app.order W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-17 05:37:24.086 2099-2118/com.order.app.order W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa0883cc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-17 05:37:26.390 2099-2118/com.order.app.order D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xa1ce1b00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xa18d8700
12-17 05:37:26.417 2099-2123/com.order.app.order E/Response:: DELETE FROM cart WHERE product_name='Club Sandwich' AND magazi_id='53' AND servitoros_id='724' AND trapezi='3'
12-17 05:37:26.430 2099-2118/com.order.app.order W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-17 05:37:26.430 2099-2118/com.order.app.order W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xa0883cc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-17 05:37:26.445 2099-2123/com.order.app.order E/Response:: DELETE FROM cart WHERE product_name='Club Sandwich' AND magazi_id='53' AND servitoros_id='724' AND trapezi='3'
```

While the Names Added is: `[BLT Sandwich, Club Sandwich]`

The response is twice the last object:

```
E/Response:: DELETE FROM cart WHERE product_name='Club Sandwich' AND magazi_id='53' AND servitoros_id='724' AND trapezi='3'
E/Response:: DELETE FROM cart WHERE product_name='Club Sandwich' AND magazi_id='53' AND servitoros_id='724' AND trapezi='3'
```

The deleteDataWebService:

```
private void deleteDataWebService(){
        DeleteData deleteData = new DeleteData();
        deleteData.execute(AppConstant.DELETE_URL);
    }
```

The PHP File:

```
<?php
ini_set("default_charset", "UTF-8");
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
try {
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=my_server;dbname=database', 'username', 'password');
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES utf8 ");
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $handler->exec("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'"); 
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$productName = $_POST['productName'];
$magazi = $_POST['magazi_id'];
$servitoros = $_POST['servitoros_id'];
$trapezi = $_POST['trapezi'];
$handler->query("DELETE FROM cart WHERE product_name='$productName' AND magazi_id='$magazi' AND servitoros_id='$servitoros' AND trapezi='$trapezi'");
die("Deleted");
?>
```

And only the last item is being deleted. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tested your API, whether its working fine?

Comment: yes it is working fine if i execute raw query

Comment: Not about rawQuery, I am asking about the API which you created?

Comment: yes it works....however i cannot delete multiple selections...only the last items from the List is being deleted

Comment: You need to modify your API, to delete multiple rows. But, by the way with this single row, whether your code works fine or not?

Comment: my code works fine i have a problemm in multiple rows

Comment: Mean, your android code is working fine?

Comment: You can modify your php code to receive a `JSON array`, parse it there. From android you can pass a JSON array for the rows.

Comment: but i execute the task for all the names in the names List....

Comment: OK, ok sorry for wrong interpretation.

Comment: Can you post `deleteDataWebService()` method?

Comment: yes but i only execute the task there

Comment: What is that `alertDialog` which you are showing?

Comment: its show in the code...in the positive button press i execute the task

Comment: then what about that for loop?

Comment: the for loop contains the list of the items i have selected.....check the responces and the names added array to see what is going on\

Comment: And you are calling the method `deleteDataWebService()` there right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98217/discussion-between-helldawg13-and-nigam-patro).

Comment: anyone any thoughts?

Comment: Please display the `DELETE` statement that is failing.

Comment: check the logcat please....you will see that in the Names  Added theres is an array with 2 different items and it only deletes the last item 2 times....this is my problemm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of asynchronous execution. Calling deleteDataWebService() method only schedules execution of DeleteData task, does not execute it instantly. Task is actually performed some time later.

Assume that you have two items to delete, in for loop:

- nameAdapter set for item1,
- task is scheduled to execute,
- nameAdapter set for item2,
- task is scheduled to execute,

Some time later

- task is executed with nameAdapter for item2,
- task is executed with nameAdapter for item2,

Passing value as parameter to async task instead of passing it via nameAdapter shared variable will solve the problem. Also nameValuePairs should not be shared between task instances.

e.g:

```
    private class DeleteData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<CartList>> {
    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    private void deleteDataInDB(String name){
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(AppConstant.PRODUCT_NAME_VALUE_PAIR, name));
        ...
    }
    ...

    @Override
    protected List<CartList> doInBackground(String... params) {
        ...
        deleteDataInDB(params[1]);
        ...
    }

    ...
}

private void deleteDataWebService(String name){
    DeleteData deleteData = new DeleteData();
    deleteData.execute(AppConstant.DELETE_URL, name);
}
```

Comment: will try that....so you mean that where i setup the namevaluepair i should pass as a parameter just what i want to delete right?

Comment: I have provided an example

Comment: it works but i have a problemm removing items from the adapter. can you help me with that?

Comment: Sure, but may be it is better to create separate question for that.

Comment: i solved it just now...thanks a lot man even on the last someone help and it was you

Answer (score 2):

Your question:

> And only the last item is being deleted. Any ideas?

Update query:

```
DELETE FROM cart
 WHERE product_name='$productName'
   AND magazi_id='$magazi'
   AND servitoros_id='$servitoros'
   AND trapezi='$trapezi'
 order by id desc limit 1
```